# How to solve the issue of Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop even I am using key props

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, mobile

Here is my code

```
return (
    <ScrollView>
      <View style={{ padding: 10, flex: 1 }}>
        {listing.map((listing) => (
          <>
            <View style={styles.containerOne} key={listing.snome_id}>
              <View
                id="listing"
                style={styles.containerTwo}
              >
                <Text style={{ margin: 15, marginTop: 20 }}>
                  {listing.header}
                </Text>

                {listing.url.map((url) => (
                  <Image style={styles.pic} source={{ uri: url }} />
                ))}

                <Text style={{ margin: 15, marginTop: 20 }}>
                  {' '}
                  {listing.description}
                </Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          </>
        ))}
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
```

I am trying to view multiple listings and the corresponding image and some text. It seems even though I am using a key prop in the view component it is still throwing error to me and I am not sure about the reason behind that.

I hope that somebody can help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key always needs to be given to the top-level component created by the map function. In your code, that's the Fragment. You'll need to replace this:

```
  <>
            <View style={styles.containerOne} key={listing.snome_id}>
 ...
  </>
```

With this:

```
  <React.Fragment key={listing.snome_id}>
            <View style={styles.containerOne}>
  ...
  </React.Fragment>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked